# Setting DataSource for Quartz Scheduler under Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a project with Spring boot and Quartz Job Scheduler.
I want to split one database for two schemas: one for project data and another for quartz data. How can i do that?

My current
**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/main-service
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=main-service
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.flyway.default-schema=main-service
spring.flyway.create-schemas=true
spring.datasource.username=${USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD}
```

Exapmle schema name for quartz: **main-service-quartz**.

I also heard about the @QuartzDataSource annotation for set datasource for quartz, but don't understand how to make it.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything pre-made, but Spring does support a concept called [data routing](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source).

Comment: it's not relevant solution for me =(

Comment: Yes, it is. One datasource for Quartz, one for project data. A datasource is just an object that points to a database, then you'd add some logic to choose the correct datasource. You could conceivably do this by service (e.g. a service that persists your quartz data) or even by entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything prebuilt into Spring for this. If it does exist, use it, but I am not aware about.
What I would do, and I had done before so I know it works, I would configure the second `quartz` data source in my `application.properties` and use that configuration to create a `QuartzDatasource` bean and use that bean as needed.

```
quqrtz.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz-service
quqrtz.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
quqrtz.datasource.hikari.schema=quartz-service
quqrtz.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
quqrtz.flyway.default-schema=quartz-service
quqrtz.flyway.create-schemas=true
quqrtz.datasource.username=${QUARTZ_USER}
quqrtz.datasource.password=${QUARTZ_PASSWORD}
```

Then you create a `@Configuration` class pointing to the `quartz` prefix and once you loaded this config you will be able to create your `quartzDatasource` bean, and if you use JPA second `entity manager` etc.

As simple is it looks, I would not go like this, especially if JPA involved. There is a big challenge. I have no idea how you can make flyway run against two data sources. There is a `@FlywayDatasorce` annotation I never used it more than once in a given application.

For me the best way to go is to grant at database level read write access to the `relations` from `quartz` schema to the application user and use a single data source for accessing both.

Or maybe even clearer if there is a logical separation between what the main service does and what the quartz service does have two separate micro services, each one doing its own job. If you go simple you can save lots of headaches later on.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, i also think about separate service, but for now it's redundant.